# osmium - add output header to PBF

Tags: openstreetmap, osmium, pyosmium

I create multiple synthetic OSM PBF files with `pyosmium` and later on I want to merge them and use `osmium` executable to set some custom headers on the PBF for archiving purposes.

However, calls such as

`osmium cat --no-progress example1.pbf example2.pbf --output-header=sorting=blabla -O -o test_data.pbf`

are not setting any headers which are viewable with `osmium fileinfo`. According to [`libosmium`'s documentation](https://osmcode.org/libosmium/manual.html#the-file-header) it should be possible to set arbitrary header key/value pairs. The only header I can permanently change is `generator`, so this works:

`osmium cat --no-progress example1.pbf example2.pbf --output-header=generator=blabla -O -o test_data.pbf`

I could imagine that the problem is that the input PBFs don't have the headers that I want to set in the output PBF (input PBFs actually do have the `generator` header). However, if that is the problem, how do I use `pyosmium` to add headers to the PBFs I create in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Was answered by the main dev of osmium in https://github.com/osmcode/osmium-tool/issues/181.

Basically the headers are pretty restricted and it's hard-coded which ones are allowed based on the output format (or input for reading).